# How do web servers avoid TIME_WAIT?

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, winsock

I'm writing a simple HTTP server and learning about TIME_WAIT.  How do real web servers in heavy environments handle requests from thousands of users without all the sockets getting stuck in TIME_WAIT after a request is handled?  (Not asking about keep-alive -- that would help for a single client, but not for thousands of different clients coming through).

I've read that you try and get the client to close first, so that all the TIME_WAITs get spread out among all the clients, instead of concentrated on the server.

How is this done?  At some point the server has to call close/closesocket.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The peer that initiates the active close is the one that goes into TIME_WAIT. So as long as the client closes the connection the client gets the TIME_WAIT and not the server. I go into this all in a little more detail [in this blog posting](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html). If you are unable to reach that link then the wayback machine [has it](http://web.archive.org/web/20220321220923/http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html).

Comment: So does the server just hang around and wait for the client to close?  I'd think at some point it would want to time out and close the connection itself.

Comment: Which makes me think of another question :)   Do you suppose a real web server (IIS/Apache?) just call select on the socket with a 5(?) second timeout -- figuring that should be plenty of time for the client to disconnect (and let select return with an error socket)?

Comment: If you reset the connection rather than closing it then you don't end up in TIME_WAIT either. So if you wanted to add a timeout for idle connections you'd close them by first turning off linger and then issuing the close. This would send an RST and you wouldnt end up in TIME_WAIT.

Comment: No. Linger off is the default. It just means no blocking in close(). A FIN is still sent. Linger on with a positive timeout causes blocking in close() for up to the timeout period. FIN is still sent. The third case is the one where RST is sent.

Comment: EJP - You're correct, I should have been more precise. By "turning off linger" I was referring to setting the linger timeout to 0 to force and abortive close. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx)